# Using time_range to filter search for latest ads / ad creatives in Facebook Graph API / Ads API

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook-ads-api

I am currently working on a small project with the FB APIs. I am trying to get the latest Posts (especially the Post IDs) which were used in ads. I already tried the FB Ads API (facebook-business-sdk for Python 3.x) and FB Graph API (facebook-sdk for Python 3.x). In both ways the API returned the data I needed, but I wasn't able to filter the results.

This is the query I tried in both ways:

`act_{ad_account_id}?fields=ads.time_range({'since': '2020-06-11', 'until': '2020-06-15'}){creative{effective_object_story_id}}`

The problem is, that I want to receive only data for last x days, which doesn't work. According to [FB Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup) it is possible, when you use time_range or date_preset param (I tried both) on the Ads-endpoint.

I also tried different syntax like `act_{ad_account_id}/ads?time_range[since]=2020-06-11&time_range[until]=2020-06-15`, but it didn't work either.

Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Looks like it is a problem to use the time_range without the insights-node, because it is for aggregating these insights-values. I have found another solution by using the `effective_status` param to filter only for ACTIVE ads. Feel free to add a solution where you can use a date filter to list the latest posts - that would be the better solution!